# cocos2d how CCSprite to appear on screen

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I want to animate the way a CCSprite appear on screen.
At the moment I'm using "addChild" to display the sprite on screen but I want it to appear on screen with animation.

Is is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading through the Cocos2D programming guide, there is a subject on animation with source code there. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but you didn't understand me
I have an image and I want it to be displayed on screen during an animation.

Comment: Can you explain a little further what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure: I have an image/ccsprite, to add it to the screen I use addChild - which adds the image/ccsprite to the screen naturally "put it and forget it"
I want the image/ccsprite to be added to screen in animation, like being dropped on screen or in moving animation.

Thank you for your patience

Comment: Oh, after you addChild set the sprite position outside of screen coords, [sprite setPosition:ccp(-100,160)]; and then do [sprite runAction: [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(340,0)]]; this should move your sprite from the left side of the screen to the center if in landscape mode.